# How to insert invisible characters in a text?

Tags: php, character-encoding, char, caramel

excuse my language, I speak Spanish

try to translate into another language is impossible

As I can put a hidden character in a text as it has this :

> Саrrоts аrе nоt јust fоr Вugs Вunnу! Іt іs а оf rісh sоurсе nесеssаrу
>   nutrіеnts аnd mіnеrаls. Іt іs а оf rісh sоurсе nесеssаrу nutrіеnts аnd
>   mіnеrаls. Іt іs оnе оf thоsе mіrасlе соnсосtіоns thаt іs gооd fоr
>   vаrіоus рurроsеs. Саrrоts hаvе а оf wеаlth vаluаblе nutrіtіоn аnd уоu
>   whеn јuісе thеm, уоu puede conseguir а оf соnсеntrаtеd dоsе thеіr
>   hеаlіng роwеr. Frоm bаlаnсіng blооd sugаr, іmрrоvіng blооd hеаlth,
>   rеlіеvіng соngеstіоn, fіghtіng іnflаmmаtіоn аnd thе сlеаnsіng kіdnеуs
>   tо рrоtесtіng еуеsіght, brаіn funсtіоn аnd fіghtіng Lеukеmіа, саrrоt
>   јuісе bеnеfіts pueden ayudarle nеаrlу еvеrу раrt оf уоur bоd Try

translating into google translator but I did not work I realized that
something strange is how do I can do?

[image]

Comment: Te recomiendo que preguntes aquí: http://es.stackoverflow.com.

Answer (score 1):

They aren't invisible characters, the text contains characters that are [homoglyphs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homoglyph). For example 'd0a1' is CYRILLIC CAPITAL LETTER ES but is visually identical to Latin capital C.  See [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IDN_homograph_attack#Cyrillic) for an explanation. To duplicate this you could write something, for example, to string replace "C" with U+0421 CYRILLIC CAPITAL LETTER ES character (`&#x0421;`).